# Symfony 2.1 validator does not see mime-type

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I'm working on Symfony 2.1 where i'm adding images to the default fosUserBundle User entity.
On top of my entity I have this:

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
* @ORM\Table(name="users")
*/
class User extends BaseUser
```

Next the concerning field:

```
/**
* @ORM\Column(nullable=true)
* @Assert\File(maxSize="5M", mimeTypes={"image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/png"})
*/
protected $promo;
```

The error I'm getting is `The mime type of the file is invalid (""). Allowed mime types are "image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/png".`.

The weird thing is, when I var_dump `$this->promo->getClientMimeType()` I neatly get `image/jpeg`...
So for some reason the validator is looking in the wrong location?

Does anybody have any idea what might cause this?

Comment: I suppose that, for some reason, you're not getting the file at all.
When do you dump? Before or after binding form?

Answer (score 4):

As it turns out it is crucial to have the `php_fileinfo` extension installed in your php.
Without it the validator can nog validate your files as it uses the `guessExtion()` method from `uploadedFile`.

This fixed my problem. However, on shared hosting this might cause trouble since you might not be able to enable php_fileinfo.