# Symfony2 - How to validate if the uploaded file is a tex file (LaTex)

Tags: php, validation, symfony, latex, mime-types

I have a file upload function in my Symfony2 project and I would like to validate that the uploaded file is a `.tex` file format => LaTex file.
For text/html, I am using:

```
$metadata->addPropertyConstraint('file', new Assert\File(array(
            'maxSize' => '100000k',
            'mimeTypes' => array("text/html"),
            'mimeTypesMessage' => 'Please upload a valid HTM/HTML File',
    )));
```

I am trying:

```
 $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('file', new Assert\File(array(
            'maxSize' => '100000k',
            'mimeTypes' => array(
                   'text/html',
                    'application/x-tex',
                    'application/x-latex'
             ),
            'mimeTypesMessage' => 'Please upload a valid HTM/HTML/TEX File',
    )));
```

But as soon as I am uploading a .tex file, I am getting the message:

```
Please upload a valid HTM/HTML/TEX File.
```

How can I add Tex file also here? Thank you.

Comment: Do you have the `php_fileinfo` extension enabled? Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12896222/symfony-2-1-validator-does-not-see-mime-type

Comment: @Max, the htm/html validation works, and it is also using mime_type, so it should be enabled.

Comment: Well you can be sure about it: just do a `phpinfo()` and search for `fileinfo`. If you find it in the list it is enabled. At least you can cross out one possible issue.

Comment: Thank you. The fileinfo is there with the version 1.0.5-dev

Comment: I'm pretty much out of ideas, but maybe look into the source code of the file validator and try to see if he's getting the right file MIME type. bear in mind the MIME type is just an suggestion and you should not rely too heavily on it. Good luck!

Comment: If you must make sure it's latex, you could check the syntax, there's the [syntonly](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/syntonly) package which does exactly that. Or the lacheck command. But what if the file depends on other files? Or if the latex file has one little syntax error? One missing bracket? How do you decide what's valid latex and what isn't? (and why does it matter?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the same principles of image validation can be applied here. It's unreliable to trust mime-type since user could plant `php` executable within `image/jpeg`.

For the images this can be verified by using `getimagesize()` function. As for the `LaTeX` you would need some 3rd-party lib what will try to open uploaded file and throw the exception on error (invalid file format, invalid expression, etc...).

Maybe this one: **[PHPLatex](http://phplatex.scarfboy.com/)**?

Also, which mime-type did you get when you tried uploading file? (@Ahmed's idea)

Answer (score 2):

Unless the submitting client 'knows' that tex files are registered as application/x-tex I believe that the client won't sent then as such.

Can you search for the `\documentclass` directive within the stream?
Alternatively if you are in control of the client machines, e.g. at work or university, can you get the mime types registered on them?

Answer (score 0):

I think you've to use the `application/x-latex` [mime-type](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types).

Comment: Hi Ahmed, Unfortunately, this is not working, I am getting the validator error message.

Comment: I tryied also with application/x-tex because my file is a .tex format, but it is not working